# Am trying to fix the height of my html table and having difficulty

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to fix the height of my html table to 320px however when I add more content the table grows. any help would be much appreciated

```html
<style>
    .blogBox {margin-bottom:20px; border-bottom:#F00 thin dotted; background-color:#f2f2ea; height:320px; overflow:hidden; table-layout:fixed;}
</style>

    <table align="left" width="220" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blogBox">
      <tr>
           <td valign="top" height="320px">
                            
               <p class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus </p>
                                
              <p class="blog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras imperdiet, lectus vel mattis mollis, lacus enim feugiat tellus, at sagittis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras imperdiet, lectus vel mattis mollis, lacus enim feugiat tellus, at sagittis perdiet, lectus vel mattis mollis, lacus enim feu s enim feu s enim feus enim feu</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Please reword your question from "any help would be much appreciated" to "how can I prevent the table from growing when extra content is added".

Comment: Can you please clear your question. If you add more content in Table. Table height should need to increase or always fixed to 320Px. Because we confused on wordings "however when i add more content the table grows".

Answer (score 2):

For `.blogBox` add `display:block;`

```
.blogBox 
{
  display:block; /*or inline-block, depend of Your need */
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-bottom:#F00 thin dotted;
  background-color:#f2f2ea;
  height:320px;
  overflow:hidden;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

There is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mtpmy55j/) . I only change `height` to `120px` for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the table inside a div with a `max-height` and stop it from going further down the page in that sense. Otherwise I don't believe you can stop the table from getting bigger with increased content. I think if you use a `tbody` tag and set it to `display:block` and give it a set height it will work but could lead to misalignment.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="pane">
   <table align="left" width="220px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blogBox">
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <p class="headline">Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p class="blog">Lorem</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.pane {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:320px;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljaxw8kr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Take `tbody` inside `table` tag and set it's style

```
{overflow:hidden; max-height:320px; display:block;}.
```

It will work for you. Or you can put your table inside a `div` tag and set it's style

```
{overflow:hidden; max-height:320px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.blog {height:320px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Add this into your CSS.